# Bootstrap typeahead not showing results

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead with Laravel 5.3.

I was using the twitter version before hand which worked fine, except the styles were broken. So I switched to this version but the drop down isn't being rendered. There are no errors either in the console.

If I open the network tab in dev tools, I can see that the request being made and data is being successfully returned. It's just not rendering the suggestion dropdown box.

Anyone know why that could be?

```
<input type="text" id="search" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off">

 var engine = new Bloodhound({
     remote: {
         url: '/find?q=%QUERY%',
         wildcard: '%QUERY%'
     },
     datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
     queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
   });
   engine.initialize();

   $("#search").typeahead({
       hint: true,
       highlight: true,
       minLength: 0,
       source:engine.ttAdapter()
   });
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar See post - "There are no errors either in the console."

Comment: Can you post your sample json response here?

Answer (score -1):

Check out my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yqy995wv/

HTML

```
<div id="remote">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Oscar winners for Best Picture">
</div>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var bestPictures = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: 'https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/films/queries/%QUERY.json',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'best-pictures',
        display: 'value',
        source: bestPictures
    });
});
```

Your JSON response should be like

```
[
  {
    "value": "All Quiet on the Western Front",
  },
  {
    "value": "Gentleman's Agreement",
  },
  {
    "value": "All the Kings Men",
  },
  {
    "value": "All About Eve",
  },
  {
    "value": "An American in Paris",
  },
  {
    "value": "Around the World in 80 Days",
  },
  {
    "value": "The Apartment",
  }
]
```

Comment: This is the twitter version... I'm not using that, I'm using the typeahead I posted a link to.